# Zabbix Proxy+Docker: Zabbix isn't getting the permission it needs to read/execute scripts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, zabbix

I'm trying to setup an ExternalCheck via Zabbix Proxy running in a Docker container, but I'm having a hard time getting Zabbix the permissions it needs to execute the script. This is the error message I keep getting:

```
Invalid discovery rule value: cannot parse as a valid JSON object: invalid object format, expected opening character '{' or '[' at: 'sh: ./root/zabbix-docker/zbx_env/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/discover_cups_printers.pl: Permission denied'
```

I ran `chmod 554 -R externalscripts | chown zabbix.zabbix -R externalscripts` in the externalscripts directory but the error persists. I've also reloaded proxy's config cache but the error is still there.

I've noticed that the proxy compose file has the external scripts volume set to read only:

```
zabbix-proxy-sqlite3:    
  volumes:
   ~ ./zbx_env/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts:/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts:ro
```

Would erasing :ro and restarting proxy solve the issue?

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why it's complaining about malformed JSON, then mentioning sh, but it's a Perl script, judging by the .pl extension, and _then_ it's reporting permission denied.

Comment: Removing `:ro` will not solve the issue, the zabbix service is running with id `1997` (by default) inside the container, and that user cannot execute the files in the `externalscripts` folder.